# Камера cv2 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cv2

Можно ли сделать как-то проверку через `cv2` на наличие камеры.

Просто я хочу сделать условие, если камера есть = делать одно, но если её нет - другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768256/10562663), который решает вашу проблему.

Сама функция проверки выглядит так

```py
import cv2

def returnCameraIndexes():
    # checks the first 10 indexes.
    index = 0
    arr = []
    i = 10
    while i > 0:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
        if cap.read()[0]:
            arr.append(index)
            cap.release()
        index += 1
        i -= 1
    return arr

cams = returnCameraIndexes()
```

Функция проверяет первые 10 индексов и возвращает доступные. Тестировал на Win10 pro.

Результат => возвращен лист `[0, 1]`. Нулевой индекс - встроенная камера, первый - внешняя.

Логично предположить, что пустой лист будет означать отсутствие камеры, можно проверить и написать логику

```py
if cams:
    # действия при наличии камеры
    pass
else:
    # действия при ее отсутствии
    pass
```